# How to limit the number of times a specific random number is generated python

Tags: python

I am currently working on a memory game in python as a class project. I am trying to generate random numbers between 0 and 3 which would correspond to a certain card. The thing is, I need each card to only appear twice. No more, and no less.

Here is my current code:

```
import random
cards = ["___TI___", "___GK___", "___QW___", "___KJ___"]
boardTemp1 = ['1', '2',
              '3', '4',
              '5', '6',
              '7', '8']

def shuffle():

    cardChoose = random.randint(0, 3)
    boardChoose = random.randint(0, 7)
    randCard = 9
    randCard = cards[cardChoose]
    boardTemp1[boardChoose] = cards[cardChoose]
    return randCard

boardTemp1[0] = shuffle()
boardTemp1[1] = shuffle()
boardTemp1[2] = shuffle()
boardTemp1[3] = shuffle()
boardTemp1[4] = shuffle()
boardTemp1[5] = shuffle()
boardTemp1[6] = shuffle()
boardTemp1[7] = shuffle()


print(boardTemp1)
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making independent random choices isn't a good approach when you have a specific set of items that you're shuffling around.  Try this instead:

```
import random
cards = ["___TI___", "___GK___", "___QW___", "___KJ___"]
boardTemp1 = cards * 2
random.shuffle(boardTemp1)
print(boardTemp1)
```

Comment: Worth noting, totally random can to humans look like the algorithem stacks the game against them. If you are looking for more "fair" random shuffles take a look at [how spotify does it](https://labs.spotify.com/2014/02/28/how-to-shuffle-songs).

Comment: @Olian04 Probably good advice in general, but in this case, it’s a memory game. As long as the cards don’t move in the middle of playing, I don’t think “stacked against them” is likely to be a thing.

Comment: @DanielH Ohh, didn't realize it was for a memory game. Then yes, general Fisher-Yates randomness would absolutely be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would list each card twice and randomize the list instead of the board, then remove each card from the list as you place it on the board:

```
import random

cards = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
random.shuffle(cards)

while cards:
    card = cards.pop()
    # place each card on the board sequentially
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you store the numbers in two lists as they are generated? 
When a number is generated:
check the lists:

-if number is not in first list, add it

-if number is in the first list, check the second

-if number is not in the second, add it

-if number is in the second list, then it has been generated twice, and do what you want from there, which is assume is to generate
   another random number.

eg something like this:

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
n=newly generated random number
if n not in list1:
    list1.append(n)
elif
  if n not in list2:
    list2.append(n)
else:
  #regenerate random number
```

Comment: you can keep a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which will be a lot easier than 2 lists

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know of Counter, but would the list method work? I appreciate the feedback, as I'm just getting into python/coding.

Comment: Ok, appreciate it.